Bias Voltage affecting op-amp at 0v
This question is a follow-up from the setup described here
Recap: I am designing a circuit which is intended to map a signal in the 0-5V range to the 1.75-7.0V range. To do this I am using an LM317T voltage regulator in conjunction with a TLC2272 Rail-to-Rail opamp. After testing the circuit in LTSpice, I got promising results with the output behaving as expected:

The problem I'm experiencing now is that when I ground my input resistor R3 (0V) I get the expected 1.75V on the output as seen here:
R3 Grounded:

However, if instead of grounding R3, I simply turn off my function generator, I get a voltage on the input which is then amplified resulting in the incorrect output voltage at 0V input voltage.
R3 connected to Function generator that is off:

How can I avoid this behavior? The end goal of this circuit is to have the input connected to something similar to a function generator (ie. a sensor signal source). The circuit behaves as expected when the generator is supplying a signal but not when it isn't. Furthermore, how do you avoid this at a high level when designing a circuit?

What is the output when the signal generator is off? 3.5 V?

@MathKeepsMeBusy Yes

When the signal generator is off, R3 is not connected directly to ground (0V), but is in a high impedance state. We can model this with some very high valued resistor connected to ground.
Because of the high impedance source feeding R3, the voltage at the non-inverting input of the op-amp will be determined primarily by the voltage output of the LM317, i.e. 1.75 V.
Since the op-amp has a feedback ratio of about 1/2, the output will be about 2 times the input voltage, or about 3.5 V, which is what you measure.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
FYI: The LM317-N is not a voltage reference, but a voltage regulator. The datasheet specifies that it needs 10 mA of load current to operate in its recommended operating area. There are better ways to get a 1.75 voltage reference, both requiring less load current, and with greater accuracy. However, if you have an LM317-N on hand, and want to use it, you can. To get a 10 mA load current, you could change the adjustment resistors from 3000 \$\Omega\$ and 1200 \$\Omega\$ to 125 \$\Omega\$ and 50 \$\Omega\$. Or, you could keep the 3000 and 1200 \$\Omega\$ resistors and add a 175 \$\Omega\$ resistor from the output of the LM317-N to ground.

Ok this makes sense to me. How would I go about mitigating this? Do I need a complete redesign?

@JaysonOkhman Why do you care what the output is when you don't supply a valid input?

Is 0V being a high impedance state specific to function generators? I am concerned that my application may behave the same.

What is your application, and why would it's output have a high impedance? The function generator has a high impedance when it is off.

My application is substituting a particular automotive sensor with another. I have an original sensor that has an output range of 1.75V -7.0V and a new sensor that I would like to use that has a output range of 0-5V. I am trying to map the 0-5V range onto the 1.75V-7.0V range.

Not sure why you are being so vague. It doesn't help you for getting good advice.

I don't understand how that is vague? I'm trying to avoid muddling the question with too many details. I have an automotive AMF sensor on an older car. This older style of sensor is restrictive and I would like to replace it with a newer MAF sensor. The AMF sensor has an output range of 1.75V-7.0V and the MAF sensor has an output range between 0V-5V. I'm designing a circuit to help me bridge that gap.
